# :hover with a nested sIFR element

Tags: javascript, css, sifr

I've got the following html:

```
<li><a href="#"><span class="font Berthold-light">1</span>Consectetur adipiscing elit risus.</a></li>
```

The number within the `span` is replaced by sIFR, but I'd like it to change color on `a:hover`. In CSS it would work like this:

```
a:hover span { color: #0fb5ef; }
```

Is there a way to do the same with sIFR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Flash does not support this.

Comment: It is, however, possible, to some extent, to emulate this using JavaScript, but I'm not sure if you should want to go there.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an excerpt of my sifr-config.js that handles hover effect on links. try and adapted for your usage.

sIFR.replace({
selector: 'h3',
src: 'flash/din.swf',
highsrc: 'flash/din.swf',
css: {
'.sIFR-root' : { 'text-transform': 'uppercase' , 'color':'#FEBF10', 'font-weight':'bold','font-size':'12px'},
'a': { 'text-decoration': 'none', 'color':'#FEBF10' },
'a:link': { 'text-decoration': 'none', 'color':'#FEBF10' },
'a:hover': { 'text-decoration': 'underline', 'color':'#FEBF10'  },
'a:visited': { 'text-decoration': 'none', 'color':'#FEBF10'  },
'a:active': { 'text-decoration': 'none', 'color':'#FEBF10'  }
},
wmode: 'transparent',
paddingTop: 0
});

Comment: I might have not explained myself well enough. I don't want to change the entire anchor, only the span nested _within_ the anchor.